# Hide the process progress bar on the toolbar in netbeans IDE?

Tags: c++, netbeans, ide, progress-bar, netbeans-8

I need to hide the progress bar which is constantly and annoyingly moving while I am debugging. How is it done?

[image]

I'm using version 8.0.2. Apparently there is an old bug related to this problem:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63332

Comment: Have you found out more on this? That progress bar is really quite annoying :/

Comment: No, I make the window height longer and hide it below my task bar!

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't completely remove the progress bar, you can move it to the top right of the screen by adding the following to etc/netbeans.conf:

```
J-Dnetbeans.winsys.statusLine.in.menuBar=true
```